# Android: Edit project properties - change app name

Tags: android, properties, project, edit

I  have a project which I  created  a few days ago as a test project  and  now  after I've done some very nice stuff with it I need to change some basic information.

I am using Eclipse IDE and I was able to change some things, such as class names. The problem is I can't figure out where to change the project name.

For the installed application on my android emulator, the text below the app icon is showing the test name. How do I change that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open `strings.xml` in your `res/values` directory and change the value in the XML element `<string name="app_name">` if you are in the 'strings.xml' view.

Alternatively, you can edit the value of app_name if you are viewing the file under the 'Resources' view.

Comment: No problem. Good luck on your app!

Answer (score 0):

If we edit application name means it will create some problem in some cases. So, don't change your app name . For that create a new string in  Project-->res--->val--->String.xml `<resources>
    <string name="app_name">ABDUL</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="rainbow">Rainbow</string>
</resources>`

Next in the Android Manifest file edit your corresponding app_name which you have given in string xml as `< activity
            android:name="com.example.ABDUL.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/rainbow" // **Modified Name**
            android:icon="@drawable/qwerty" >

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>`
```